# Check readyState of a window opened using window.open

Tags: javascript

I have a JS script that opens a pdf in a new tab.

```
var newWindow = window.open("url", "docWindow");
```

Is it possible to check if that document has loaded without running a script on that window, to check the `readyState` status of that document from the original tab?

Comment: Your question title and question body seem to be from two completely different questions. What question are you really trying to ask?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe, this should be possible with `window` this way:

```
newWindow.onload = function () {
  // Do stuff after window is loaded.
};
```

For the ReadyState, you can use the `window.document`:

```
newWindow.document.readyState;
```

Set an event handler on the `readyState` and call your opening function.

```
newWindow.document.onreadystatechange = function () {
  if (newWindow.document.readyState === "complete") {
    // Call the code.
  }
}
```

Comment: I tried inside a chrome extension to open popup and inject code but the sample didn't work at all..

Comment: @CodeCooker Won't work for Chrome Extensions plus this solution won't work at all. You need to use fetch.  It's a solution that's 5 years old, please don't expect it to work for a browser, [which changes every 6 weeks](https://chromium.googlesource.com/chromium/src/+/master/docs/process/release_cycle.md).

Comment: Kumar, Thanks.  Why don't you update or add a note then? this would make sense now.

Answer (score 0):

After struggling I found the best solution from jquery webpage.

https://learn.jquery.com/using-jquery-core/document-ready/

```
$( window ).on( "load", function() {
    console.log( "window loaded" );
});
```

After the entire window is loaded you can run your code. Hope this helps someone in future.

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/31840801)